# Is it possible to poke text out the left boundary of a document?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, amsthm

So here I'm using AMS's `newtheorem` as

```
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{exDfn}[dfn]{Extended Definition}
```

Which I would like to ask if it is possible to left shift the exDfn so that Definition lines up. Something like no matter what, just shift the whole text leftward. Something like the following:

```
         Definition 1. something blahblahblah
         def 1's second line
Extended Definition 2. Extra/optional definitions something
         exDef's second line.
```

Comment: You could do something along the lines of `\newtheorem{exDfn}[dfn]{\makebox[0pt][r]{Extended }Definition}` but are you really sure you want *that*?

Comment: @campa It seems to be working, but if possible I would like to use units (relatively) with something like left shift n half-spaces. (Actually since I'm dealing with Chinese document, where all our words are 1 full-space, or 2 half-spaces wide, It'll be quite convenient if I could just say shift a certain amount of spaces rather than fiddling with the pts as unit.)

Comment: `\newtheorem{exDfn}[dfn]{\sbox0{Extended Definition}\makebox[\dimexpr\wd0-3ex][r]{\copy0}}`, where `3ex` is the desired amount of leftward shift. A better way to express would be `\newcommand\shiftleft[1]{\sbox0{#1}\makebox[\dimexpr\wd0-3ex][r]{\copy0}}
\newtheorem{exDfn}[dfn]{\shiftleft{Extended Definition}}`

Comment: @Andrew.Wolphoe: or you could just put all the text you want shifted inside the `\makebox` where campa's comment has "Extended". camp's comment has no actual fiddling with pts (it creates a box of zero width putting text inside, right-aligned, allowing to protrude to the left if necessary).

Comment: If you want to actually fiddle around with lengths, and since you are using a fixed-width font, you could actually use the `\newtheoremstyle` command from `amsthm` to define a theorem style with a negative indentation.

Comment: @Andrew.Wolphoe -- The information that the document is in Chinese, and words are in reliably measurable units, would be much more valuable in your question than in a comment.  Please edit it into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen some suggestions that includes formatting commands inside the `\newtheorem` declarations. This can actually break other packages that access theorem labels through `\newtheorem`, such as the `theoremref` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{theoremref}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{exDfn}[dfn]{\llap{Extended }Definition}
\begin{document}

\begin{dfn}\thlabel{dfn1}
         Definition 1. something blahblahblah
         def 1's second line
\end{dfn}

\begin{exDfn}\thlabel{dfn2}
 Definition 2. Extra/optional definitions something
         exDef's second line.
\end{exDfn}


Let's refer to \thref{dfn1} and then \thref{dfn2}
\end{document}
```

Yields

[image]

which is less than ideal. If you must shift the label, try declaring a new theorem style instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{theoremref}

\newlength{\mywidth}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{\bfseries Extended } % measure the width of "Extended " in the font used

\newtheoremstyle{extplain}{}{}{\itshape}%
        {-\mywidth}  % Four argument: indent amount, set to negative of the part we want to eat
        {\bfseries}{.}{ }{}

\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}

\theoremstyle{extplain}
\newtheorem{exDfn}[dfn]{Extended Definition}
\begin{document}

\begin{dfn}\thlabel{dfn1}
         Definition 1. something blahblahblah
         def 1's second line
\end{dfn}

\begin{exDfn}\thlabel{dfn2}
 Definition 2. Extra/optional definitions something
         exDef's second line.
\end{exDfn}


Let's refer to \thref{dfn1} and then \thref{dfn2}
\end{document}
```

Here instead of guessing and checking, I defined a length variable to be equal to the width of "Extended " in bold face, and defined a `\newtheoremstyle` to be exactly the same as the default `plain` style of `amsthm`, except with a *negative* indent amount. This time the output from `\thref` is ok.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can define the theorem environment with `\newtheorem` as usual, with a zero width box. If you need to do named references, use `cleveref`.

The `cleveref` package and the `\crefname` and `\Crefname` declarations are optional, if you only plan to use `\ref` (or don't do cross-references).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{extdefinition}[definition]{\makebox[0pt][r]{Extended }Definition}

\crefname{extdefinition}{extended definition}{extended definitions}
\Crefname{extdefinition}{Extended definition}{Extended definitions}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{def1}
A nonsense definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{extdefinition}\label{def2}
Another nonsense definition, but extended
\end{extdefinition}

These are the named references: \cref{def1} and \cref{def2}

These are the named references: \Cref{def1} and \Cref{def2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would have found it very helpful if you had provided an MWE. Having never used AMS's `newtheorem` I had to do a lot of searching to find it.

The basic TeX `\llap{text}` macro typesets `text` to the left. Below is my attempt at an MWE that does what you want although I have no idea what your theorems are meant to look like.

```
% theoremprob.tex  SE 590528
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{exDfn}[dfn]{\llap{Extended }Definition}
\begin{document}

\begin{dfn}
         Definition 1. something blahblahblah
         def 1's second line
\end{dfn}

\begin{exDfn}
 Definition 2. Extra/optional definitions something
         exDef's second line.
\end{exDfn}

\end{document}
```

[image]